# Jenkins + Gradle Wrapper. How to add init.gradle settings to Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

I've just started to use Jenkins for CI with Gradle build tool for my project.
According to [Jenkins Gradle Integration: Invoke Gradle vs. Use Gradle Wrapper options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064631)  I should use Gradle wrapper, because I define custom maven URL in init.gradle.

Code below is init.gradle on my computer.

```
allprojects {
    buildscript.repositories {
        maven { url "url here" }
    }
    buildscript.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.cacheDynamicVersionsFor 0, 'seconds'
        resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url "url here" }
    }
}
```

How can I configure Jenkins to use this settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just added

```
--init-script "path to init.gradle"
```

into Gradle Switches field and it worked

Comment: Or you can use a Configuration file from https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin