# Docker with both Jar and Gradle executions in it for jenkins

Tags: jenkins, docker

I currently have the following docker file

```
FROM openjdk:8
EXPOSE 8080
WORKDIR /usr/bin/app
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar"]
```

which I build locally and run as

```
docker run -d -P -v $(pwd):/usr/bin/app/ jachno/jarrunner /usr/bin/app/build/libs/com.onboarding-service-0.0.1.jar
```

so basically the docker container has the local volume mapped to it and the name of a JAR that I want to run.

this is so I can test my acceptance tests vi jenkins. What I would really like is a container to do both for me.

so I essentially I would like to pass the name of the jar to the container. Have it run the jar file

and then run a single gradle command, in this case gradle AcceptanceTest

I know I how to install gradle in to the container and get that to run standalone, but I can't see how I run the gradle command after I have passed the name of the jar to it on start up.

is there away to have 2 entry points for a container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your requirements correctly, but hopefully I can give some help.

You can't have two entrypoints to docker image, but you still have at least two choices on how to run two commands on an image.

1) Create a startup script to your `jarrunner` image and use that as an entrypoint. Script should run first the jar file (name given as command line arguments or environment variable) and then the test command.

2) Use the `jarrunner` image as you are doing now. When the container is running, use `docker exec <container id/name> gradle AcceptanceTest` to run another command on the same container.

Comment: I went with option one and it is working really well thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could just run a groovy image like https://github.com/niaquinto/docker-gradle and just pass on the gradle commands.

For example,

`docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/usr/bin/app:rw niaquinto/gradle clean war`

where 'clean war' would be equivalent to 'gradle clean war'

Docker store link - https://store.docker.com/community/images/niaquinto/gradle

Since you also mentioned about Jenkins, it would be more efficient if you could use the gradle plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gradle+Plugin) provided by Jenkins. You could invoke from this plugin any local gradle installation.

Here's another discussion which might be useful.  [Jenkins Gradle Integration: Invoke Gradle vs. Use Gradle Wrapper options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064631/jenkins-gradle-integration-invoke-gradle-vs-use-gradle-wrapper-options)